# Accessing Property With Whitespace - Send an HTTP Request

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am using the HTTP Request function to access an API for stock market data. The issue is that I don't know how to access the JSON object using Adaptive Expression because the property has whitespace.

${dialog.api_response.content.Global Object} is not a valid adaptive expression because of the whitespace.

${dialog.api_response.content.Global+Object} also doesn't work.

${dialog.api_response.content.Global+' '+Object} is also not a valid adaptive expression to access the property.

[Error accessing access the inner property called "Global Quote"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAmn8.png)

[The syntax error in composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSFUS.png)

Is there a way to add whitespace to my property call, so I can access the "Global Quote" section of the dialog memory?